# cannot build tensorflow in Ubuntu 1604

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu, build, ubuntu-16.04

My Env:

- Ubuntu 1604
- Python 3.5.2
- bazel 0.9.0
- JDK 1.8.0_152

**My problem:**

I have ran the command `./configure` before built the tensorflow source code. But I till get following error:

```
no such target '@local_config_git//:gen/spec.json': target 'gen/spec.json' not declared in package ......
```

---

Please specify optimization flags to use during compilation when bazel option "--config=opt" is specified [Default is -march=native]:

Add "--config=mkl" to your bazel command to build with MKL support.
Please note that MKL on MacOS or windows is still not supported.
If you would like to use a local MKL instead of downloading, please set the environment variable "TF_MKL_ROOT" every time before build.

Would you like to interactively configure ./WORKSPACE for Android builds? [y/N]: n
Not configuring the WORKSPACE for Android builds.

Configuration finished

root@ubuntu:/tensorflow# bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
......................................
ERROR: /tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:1653:1: no such target '@local_config_git//:gen/spec.json': target 'gen/spec.json' not declared in package '' defined by /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/68a62076e91007a7908bc42a32e4cff9/external/local_config_git/BUILD and referenced by '//tensorflow/core:version_info_gen'
ERROR: /tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:1653:1: no such target '@local_config_git//:gen/head': target 'gen/head' not declared in package '' defined by /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/68a62076e91007a7908bc42a32e4cff9/external/local_config_git/BUILD and referenced by '//tensorflow/core:version_info_gen'
ERROR: /tensorflow/tensorflow/core/BUILD:1653:1: no such target '@local_config_git//:gen/branch_ref': target 'gen/branch_ref' not declared in package '' defined by /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/68a62076e91007a7908bc42a32e4cff9/external/local_config_git/BUILD and referenced by '//tensorflow/core:version_info_gen'
ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package' failed; build aborted: Loading failed
INFO: Elapsed time: 29.514s
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (113 packages loaded)
    currently loading: tensorflow/core/kernels
root@ubuntu:/tensorflow#

---

[ERROR information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEapX.jpg)

Comment: Please paste error in question itself instead of image.